# Adb Command to get network type of device

Tags: android, networking, adb

Is there any adb command to get network type(Like CDMA, GSM,LTE,EVDO) of device in android?

Answer (score 3):

Current connection type is stored in gsm.network.type system property. So

```
getprop gsm.network.type
```